# Sonar Service Fails to start after updating C# Plugin to 3.1

Tags: sonarqube

I updated core C# plugin to 3.1 from the update centre. Once i restarted the service Sonar Service failed to start.

The Log Message :
org.sonar.updatecenter.common.exception.IncompatiblePluginVersionException: The plugins 'csharpstylecop' and 'csharp' must have exactly the same version as they belong to the same group.

After the updated i still see csharpstylecop plugin is 2.1 and i even i don't find the csharpstylecop 3.1 available in the maven repository.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.dotnet.csharp/sonar-csharp-stylecop-plugin

Is that a pre-requsite to install the csharpstylecop 3.1 (which is not available) or the C# plugin will take care (which is not happening).

Any help here is appreciated.

Thanks,
Santhosh.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the update center to upgrade from the .NET 2.1 plugins to the 3.x series.

Please refer to the following migration guide: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/EIBMDg